# Which control to use to display more than one row and column returned from a query?

Tags: vb.net, data-binding

I have this SQL query:

```
SELECT        exitHour, [date], enterHour, total
FROM            enterAndExit
WHERE        (id = ?)
```

Which control should I use to display the "new table" that I get from this query?
since a label is good only to display a single row.

Answer (score 1):

Your should use a DataGridView. This is Microsoft's documentation on the [DataGridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.aspx). You can find a tutorial on using a DataGridView [here](http://vb.net-informations.com/datagridview/vb.net_datagridview_tutorial.htm).

Answer (score 0):

The most common control used for such tasks in WinForm projects is the [DataGridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.aspx) control.